# How can I pass a parameter to my validator without breaking DI registration? (FluentValidation)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation, .net-7.0

I need to pass a parameter from a parent validator to a child validator, by using `.SetValidator()` but having trouble with registering a validator to the DI container using FluentValidation's [automatic registration](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html#automatic-registration), when the validator is parameterized.

**Parent Validator**:

```
public class FooValidator: AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar)
            .SetValidator(foo => new BarValidator(foo.SomeStringValue))
            .When(foo => foo.Bar != null);
    }
}
```

**Child Validator:**

```
public class BarValidator: AbstractValidator<Bar>
{
    public BarValidator(string someStringValue)
    {
        RuleFor(bar => bar.Baz)
            .Must(BeValid(bar.Baz, someStringValue)
            .When(bar => bar.Baz != null);
    }
    
    private static bool BeValid(Baz baz, string someStringValue)
    {
        return baz == someStringValue; 
    }

}
```

**DI registration**

```
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

**Error message**

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FluentValidation.IValidator`1[Domain.ValueObjects.Bar] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Application.Common.Validators.BarValidator': 
    Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Application.Common.Validators.BarValidator'.)
```

```
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Application.Common.Validators.BarValidator'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Program.cs:line 9
```

- .NET 7
- FluentValidation v11.2.2
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Any ideas?

Have tried circumventing the use of automatic registration by filtering it out and registering it manually, but this changes nothing.

```
_ = services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), ServiceLifetime.Transient, filter => filter.ValidatorType != typeof(BarValidator));
_ = services.AddTransient<IValidator<Bar>>(_ => new BarValidator(""));
```

Comment: You could try adding a parameterless ctor with no validation rules essentially saying that when Fluent validates Foo.Bar automatically, it shouldn't validate anything.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but sadly I've tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Fluent Validators .WithState method  and it will pass an additional object:

```
     RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar)
        .SetValidator(foo => new BarValidator())
        .When(foo => foo.Bar != null)
        .WithState(foo => foo.SomeStringValue);
```

And then the child validator will look something like this where you won't be passing a parameter to BarValidator and we will use GetState method on the Validation Context object:

```
  public class BarValidator: AbstractValidator<Bar>
 {
       public BarValidator()
{
    RuleFor(bar => bar.Baz)
        .Must(BeValid)
        .When(bar => bar.Baz != null);
}

private bool BeValid(Baz baz, ValidationContext<Bar> context)
{
string someStringValue = context.GetState<string>();
return baz == someStringValue; 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've got yourself a chicken and egg problem. The `AbstractValidator<T>` can't have parameters in its ctor, without them also being added to the DI container. At the time the container validates itself, it doesn't know how to instantiate an instance of `AbstractValidator<T>` because it can't resolve its `string` dependency.

`AbstractValidator<T>` isn't the right tool for the job. Have a look at [Reusable Property Validators](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#reusable-property-validators). Using `PropertyValidator<Foo, Bar>` you can access `SomeStringValue` from `ValidationContext<Foo>`.

##### Child Validator:

```
public class BarValidator : PropertyValidator<Foo, Bar>
{
    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<Foo> context, Bar bar)
    {
        if (bar != null && bar.Baz != context.InstanceToValidate.SomeStringValue)
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument(nameof(Foo.SomeStringValue), context.InstanceToValidate.SomeStringValue);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override string Name => "BazValidator";

    protected override string GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode)
        => "Baz must be equal to {SomeStringValue}.";
}
```

##### Parent Validator:

```
public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar).SetValidator(new BarValidator());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create a factory that will create the validator with the required parameters.

```
public class FooValidator: AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar)
            .SetValidator(foo => MyValidatorFactory.CreateBarValidator(foo.SomeStringValue))
            .When(foo => foo.Bar != null);
    }
}

public static class MyValidatorFactory
{
    public static IValidator<Bar> CreateBarValidator(string someStringValue)
    {
        return new BarValidator(someStringValue);
    }
}

public class BarValidator: AbstractValidator<Bar>
{
    public BarValidator(string someStringValue)
    {
        RuleFor(bar => bar.Baz)
            .Must(BeValid(bar.Baz, someStringValue)
            .When(bar => bar.Baz != null);
    }
    
    private static bool BeValid(Baz baz, string someStringValue)
    {
        return baz == someStringValue; 
    }

}
```

Finally, make sure you add the factory to the DI container.

```
   services.AddTransient<Func<string, IValidator<Bar>>>(MyValidatorFactory.CreateBarValidator);
```